# Angular2 | Typescript How to call a function on a property with Unit Types

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have the following class in Angular2

```
export class Person {
    public children: Person[] | (() => Person[])
}
```

So, my intent is to have the children property to be either an array of a function that can get me the array. Without getting into why this class is structured that way, I would like to see if anyone has had the same issue with typescript complaning about the type when trying to call person.children().

The error is:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature
```

[Error given by TypeScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laeFe.png)

Now, if I cast person as "any", the Typescript error goes away (as expected) and javascript executes the function no problem.

Is there any way I can avoid that cast?

Comment: This certainly seems like a code smell.  The compiler is just trying to remind you of that fact.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

You need to use a `type guard` (more https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html) so that typescript knows that its not going to be an `array` at that point. e.g.

```
class Person {
    public children: Person[] | (() => Person[])
}

const person = new Person();
if (typeof person.children === 'function'){
    person.children();
}
```

Tested with [alm.tools](http://alm.tools/)

[image]